# How can I force SBT to use scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have a Spark project that is being built with SBT.  It sought to be using scala 2.11.7, and I've indicated this in my build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

autoScalaLibrary := false

scalaVersion := "2.11.7-local"

scalaHome := Some(file("/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.7/libexec"))
```

some might say that I've over-indicated it in fact.

regardless, when I launch the jar:

```
spark-submit  --properties-file conf/devdefaults.conf output/logdata-demo.jar
```

a line that checks the scala version prints:

```
version 2.10.4
```

Why is this happening, and how can I force the system to build using 2.11.7?

Comment: What version of Spark are you using for your `spark-submit`?

Comment: I'm using version 1.4.1

Comment: d'oh..... ok....  yeah, I feel dumb

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/

Comment: As you can read http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html it states "Spark runs on Java 6+ (...) For the Scala API, Spark 1.4.1 uses Scala 2.10. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.10.x)"

Comment: yeah.... I see that now

Comment: Actually, you can build Spark with Scala 2.11 but not all the features are implemented yet.

Comment: I saw that once I stopped focusing on SBT and actually started looking at the spark execution environment.  For now I'll just tune back  to 2.10